# Obtaining number of block parameters

Tags: ruby, methods

I need to obtain the number of parameters a given block takes. For example:

```
foobar(1,2,3) { |a, b, c|
}

def foobar(x, y, z, &block)
  # need to obtain number of arguments in block
  # which would be 3 in this example
end
```

This is possible in the 1.9 trunk, but not in any official release. I was hoping if there's any way to do this without having to download a separate gem/extension module.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you materialize a block with &, it becomes a Proc object, which has an `arity` method.  Just be careful - it returns the one's complement if the proc takes a *splat arg.

```
def foobar(x, y, z, &block)
  p block.arity
end
```

(Answer via "The Ruby Programming Language" book.)

Comment: Right. Note that `{ || nil }` will have an arity of 0, but `{ nil }` will have an arity of -1.

Comment: @CurtSampson For `RUBY_VERSION => "2.0.0"` i get the expected arity of 0 for `{nil}`

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you're looking for...

```
def foobar(x, y, z, &block)
  # need to obtain number of arguments in block
  # which would be 3 in this example
  case block.arity
    when 0 
      yield "i have nothing"
    when 1
      yield "I got ONE block arg"
    when 2
      yield "I got TWO block args"
    when 3
      yield "I got THREE block args"
  end
end

foobar(1,2,3) { |a, b, c|
    puts a
}
```

Outputs:

```
D:\ruby\bin>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i386-mswin32]

D:\ruby\bin>ruby c:\Temp.rb
I got THREE block args
```

See also - [A Ruby HOWTO: Writing A Method That Uses Code Blocks](http://blog.codahale.com/2005/11/24/a-ruby-howto-writing-a-method-that-uses-code-blocks/) from codahale.com

Comment: Hi Gishu. Thanks for the article, I'll definitely need to read through this.