# Block with two parameters

Tags: ruby

I found this code by user Hirolau:

```
def sum_to_n?(a, n)
  a.combination(2).find{|x, y| x + y == n}
end

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sum_to_n?(a, 9)  # => [4, 5]
sum_to_n?(a, 11) # => nil
```

How can I know when I can send two parameters to a predefined method like `find`? It's not clear to me because sometimes it doesn't work. Is this something that has been redefined?

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1077751/196834

Comment: To be clear, find takes 1 optional argument and a block. The block takes two arguments.

Comment: I am hirolau and I approve of this message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `Enumerable#find`, you see that it accepts only one parameter to the block. The reason why you can send it two, is because Ruby conveniently lets you do this with blocks, based on it's "parallel assignment" structure:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]].each {|x,y,z| puts "#{x}#{y}#{z}"}
# 123
# 456
```

So basically, each yields an array element to the block, and because Ruby block syntax allows "expanding" array elements to their components by providing a list of arguments, it works.

You can find more tricks with block arguments [here](http://www.paperplanes.de/2012/2/16/fun-with-ruby-block-parameters.html).

`a.combination(2)` results in an array of arrays, where each of the sub array consists of 2 elements. So:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.combination(2)
# => [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

As a result, you are sending one array like `[1,2]` to find's block, and Ruby performs the parallel assignment to assign 1 to `x` and 2 to `y`.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772441/can-someone-explain-why-this-way-of-iterating-a-nested-data-structure-does-work/31772473#31772473) SO question, which brings other powerful examples of parallel assignment, such as this statement:

```
a,(b,(c,d)) = [1,[2,[3,4]]]
```

Comment: And then how can I learn things like "parallel assignment", "decomposition" and how Ruby "Block syntax allows expanding array elements" I mean, I have read several books and on line tutorials and never read of this, can you give me a hint to start looking for please? Thanks for the response BTW.

Comment: I don't have a great resource for you. The best book I've read about Ruby is "Metaprogramming Ruby" by Paolo Perrotta (published by The Pragmatic Programmers), but I just checked - it does not mention these. This is kind of a useful edge case of parallel assignment explained in most tutorials (e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm). There are things in the language that even experienced developers keep learning, and the more code you read the more tricks you'll get up your sleeve. I definitely recommend that book, though. Easy to read and you'll get a lot out of it.

Answer (score 3):

`find` does not take two parameters, it takes one. The reason the block in your example takes two parameters is because it is using destruction. The preceding code `a.combination(2)` gives an array of arrays of two elements, and `find` iterates over it. Each element (an array of two elements) is passed at a time to the block as its single parameter. However, when you write more parameters than there is, Ruby tries to adjust the parameters by destructing the array. The part:

```
find{|x, y| x + y == n}
```

is a shorthand for writing:

```
find{|(x, y)| x + y == n}
```

Comment: I believe it's 'destructuring' not decomposition. +1 for giving the paren alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The `find` function iterates over elements, it takes a single argument, in this case a block (which does take two arguments for a hash):

```
h = {foo: 5, bar: 6}
result = h.find {|k, v| k == :foo && v == 5}
puts result.inspect #=> [:foo, 5]
```

The block takes only one argument for arrays though unless you use destructuring.

Update: It seems that it is destructuring in this case.

Comment: In case of a hash, `to_a` is implicitly applied, so it is the same as with an array.

Comment: Yes. I must admit that the `combination` method returned a hash and wanted to give a simple answer without going into destructuring and stuff but I missed the point.